# PGI 14.6 OpenSuse 13.1 x_64 gcc 4.8 c++11 compilation errors

Tags: gcc, c++11, pgi

I am trying to compile a C++ program with c++11 features using the PGI 14.6 on OpenSuse.
Unfortunaltey I Am getting the following errors

```
"/usr/include/c++/4.8/type_traits", line 269: error: identifier "__float128"
      is undefined
  struct __is_floating_point_helper<__float128>
                                    ^

"/opt/pgi/linux86-64/14.6/include-gcc48/cmath", line 71: error: no instance of
      overloaded function "std::isfinite" matches the specified type
  isfinite<double>(double __f)
  ^


"/opt/pgi/linux86-64/14.6/include-gcc48/cmath", line 100: error: no instance
      of overloaded function "std::isnormal" matches the specified type
  isnormal<double>(double __f)
  ^
```

My configuration is the following:

```
pgi 14.6
OpenSuse 13.1 x_64
gcc 4.8
compiler flag: --c++11
```

Any Help will be highly appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is apparently a known issue

TPR#20490:  pgc++ --c++11 fails to compile certain gnu 4.8 header files
Upgrade the pgc++ header files to be compatible with gnu 4.8

that has been solved with the pgi 14.7 release.